# Clarification of Zariski's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

In wikipedia [Zariski's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski's_lemma) is the following

> Let $K$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra and suppose that $K$ is a field. Then $K$ is a field extension of $k$.

But if $M$ be a maximal ideal and $A$ is a finitely generated $C$-algebra($C$= complex numbers) then one can consider the induced surjective homomorphism from $A$ to $A/M$ and therefore $A/M$ is also a finitely generated $C$-algebra but $A/M$ is a field so $A/M$ should be equal $C$ which is not since its elements are cosets. So I am wondering does Zariski lemma mean that $K$ is isomorphic to a finite field extension of k?

Comment: The first sentence is missing something. You want $K/k$ to have finite degree. One usually identifies $\mathbb{C}$ with its image here but the assertion is, I guess, that $A/M$ is a finite extension of the image of $\mathbb{C}$ in $A/M$. The ambiguity isn't super important.

Comment: Protip: use punctuation.